# CreateInstance inside Extension Method not allowed?

Tags: entity-framework-core, extension-methods, iqueryable

I'm trying to convert my `IQueryable<TEntity>` results to `IEnumerable<TDomainModel>` via an extension method.

```
IEnumerable<DeviceModel> resultEntities =  _unitofwork.PersonDeviceRepository
.GetUnassociatedDevices()
.AddFilters(deviceByTypeQueryObject.AsExpression())
.ToDomainModels<DeviceModel,Device>();
```

The IQueryable Extension is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TDomainModel> ToDomainModels<TDomainModel, TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryableEntities)
{
IEnumerable<TDomainModel> domainModels = 
queryableEntities
.Select(indiv => (TDomainModel)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TDomainModel), indiv));
return domainModels;
}
```

It compiles but errors in runtime:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'System.RuntimeType' which is being passed as an argument to the method 'CreateInstance'.
```

But it works if the `Activator.CreateInstance` conversion is NOT done in as part of an extension method. ie: in a regular method

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

I was feeding an `IQueryable` to the Extension method, but it doesn't work. It had nothing to do with the `CreateInstance`.

It worked after first converting the `IQueryable` to `AsEnumerable`, then fed it to the `ToDomainModel` extension method.

```
IEnumerable<DeviceModel> resultEntities = _unitofwork.PersonDeviceRepository.GetUnassociatedDevices().AddFilters(deviceByTypeQueryObject.AsExpression()).AsEnumerable().ToDomainModels<Device,DeviceModel>();
```

The extension method was rewritten for `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`

```
        public static IEnumerable<TDomainModel> ToDomainModels<TEntity, TDomainModel>(this IEnumerable<TEntity> enumerableEntities)
        {
            IEnumerable<TDomainModel> domainModels = queryableEntities.Select(indiv => (TDomainModel)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TDomainModel), indiv));
            return domainModels;
        }
```